# Visual Studio 2012 Simple EMGU Image to Text Solution Error

Tags: image-processing, ocr, emgucv

I feel like I've tried a bunch of different things but I cannot get passed this error.

```
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
```

Below is the VS2012 solution I am using to create an Image to Text spike using the EMGU engine.

Would someone please take a look and give my solution a try?

http://andrewherrick.com/spike/img2text.zip

[image]

Comment: It runs ok for me - no error message - although I've no idea what you're expecting. I'm running VS2012 on Windows 8.1 x64. Can you give more details about how to get the error?

Comment: its supposed to read the image and convert it to text. is that working for you?

Comment: Well it shows a cmd windows for a few seconds, then ends without error. Where is the output supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

In Debug, if I breakpoint after `var text = ocr.GetText()`, this is what I get in `text` in the Watch window:

> "Adobc, 1h: Adobc logo, Acrobat, 1h: Acrobat logo, Acrobat Ciplllft,
>   Adobc Garammld, Adobc\r\nIlllclligclll DOCIImCIII Phffmm, Adobc mar,
>   Adobc Rcadu, Adobc Sohllions Ntlwmk, Aldus,\r\nDislillu, cPzpn:
>   EXITUHL FrZmtD/hkn’, Ilhxsirzlor, lllDcSiyl, MiIIiOIL Myriad,
>   PzgcMzku,\r\nPluoloshop,l7oclk1 PoslScripl, and mvi? arc auioo
>   rcgisluad irzdmmrks or irzdmmrks ofAdobc\r\nSysluns Ilmmpmzlad iii uio
>   uiiiioii Slams moi olhu COIIIIhiCS Microsoﬂ m \Vindo\v5 arc\r\nauioo
>   rcgislaad irzdmmrks or irzdmmrks oi Microsoﬂ Cmpmzﬁml iii uio uiiiioii
>   Slams “mo,\r\nolhn’ COIIIIhiCS App]: Mac Macintosh, and Powu Macintosh
>   arc irzdmmrks oi App]:\r\nCompuln: Inc Jcgislued iii 1h: uiiiioii
>   Slams m olhu COIIIIhiCS mm is z rcgislaad irzdmmrk\r\noi mm Cmpmzﬁml
>   iii uio uiiiioii Slams Sllll is z irzdmmrk or rcyslued irzdmmrk oi
>   siiii\r\nMicrosysluns, Inc iii uio uiiiioii Slams and olhn’ COIIIIhiCS
>   mix is z rcgislaad irzdmmrk oi\r\nTh: 0pm Group SVG is z irzdmmrk oﬂhc
>   V/orld “lid: \Vcb Omlsorlium marks ofthc \V3C arc\r\nrcgsluad and
>   hcld by its MslMTf, mm and Kcio Hclvclica and Timcs arc\r\nrcyslued
>   hZdcmJrkS oi Liiioiyponou AG andkvr its subsidiarics Aria] and TimCS
>   Ncw Roman\r\narc irzdmmrks oi Th: Monolypc Cmpmzﬁml rcgislaad iii 1h:
>   u s Pzlcnl and Trldcmirk onioo\r\nm may b: rcgisluad iii Cﬁﬂill olhu
>   jlxisdicliolﬁ rrc by!‘ Dingbats is z rcyslued
>   irzdmmrk\r\nOfllllﬂllaﬁollz] Typchcc Cmpmzﬁml Ryiiiiiiii Light is z
>   irzdmmrk oi Morisawz Rn Co, Lid All\r\nolhn’ irzdmmrks arc uio propmy
>   oflhcir rcspcdivc OWIIHS\r\n\r\n"

If it helps, here's what I get in the VS2012 Output window after running in Debug:

```
'Img2Text.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
'Img2Text.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'
'Img2Text.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'
'Img2Text.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'
'Img2Text.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'
'Img2Text.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'
'Img2Text.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'
'Img2Text.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Data\img2text\Img2Text\Img2Text\bin\Debug\Img2Text.vshost.exe'
'Img2Text.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'
'Img2Text.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'
'Img2Text.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'
'Img2Text.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'
'Img2Text.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'
'Img2Text.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'
The thread 'vshost.NotifyLoad' (0x17e8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x12bc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'Img2Text.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Data\img2text\Img2Text\Img2Text\bin\Debug\Img2Text.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Img2Text.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Data\img2text\Img2Text\Img2Text\bin\Debug\Emgu.CV.OCR.dll'
'Img2Text.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Data\img2text\Img2Text\Img2Text\bin\Debug\Emgu.Util.dll'
'Img2Text.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Data\img2text\Img2Text\Img2Text\bin\Debug\Emgu.CV.dll'
The thread 'vshost.RunParkingWindow' (0x1cc4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x140c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[7864] Img2Text.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: weird... good to know it does work elsewhere... i'm just trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong or what is different about my environment